# Checking unbiasedness of $\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(X_i-X_j)^2$ for $\sigma^2$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$, be i.i.d random variables having $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ distribution, where $\mu ∈\mathbb{R}$ and
$ \sigma > 0$. Define

$$\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(X_i-X_j)^2$$

Then $W$, as an estimator of $\sigma^2$, is

$(A)$ biased and consistent

$(B)$ unbiased and consistent

$(C)$ biased and inconsistent

$(D)$ unbiased and inconsistent

I have figured out the solution by multiplying and diving by $\sqrt{2}\sigma$ making it chi-square etc. I was actually trying to figure this problem properly by opening squares. I am getting confused in summations.

$E\left(\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(X_i-X_j)^2 \right)=\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(E(X_i^2)+E(X_j^2)-2E(X_i)E(X_j))=\dfrac{1}{2n^2}\sum_{i}\sum_{j}(\mu^2+\sigma^2+\mu^2+\sigma^2-2\mu^2)$

When I solve it I get it unbiased but it's not. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac1{2n(n-1)}\sum_{i,j}(X_i-X_j)^2$ is the usual sample variance with divisor $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be due to the fact that when $i=j$, $E(X_iX_i)\neq E(X_i)E(X_i)$, because $E(X_i)E(X_i)=\mu^2, E(X_iX_i)=\sigma^2+\mu^2$

$$E(\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i} (X_i-X_j)^2)=...\\
=\frac{1}{2n^2}\sum_i\sum_{j\neq i}(\mu^2+\sigma^2+\mu^2+\sigma^2-2\mu^2)\\
=\frac{n(n-1)}{n^2}\sigma^2 $$

Comment: So how do I solve it? Could you please solve it completely? How do I utilize both of them simultaneously